# How to send message on whatsup group using Gupshup API

Tags: laravel-5, whatsapi, gupshup

I have send whatsup message to single user using Gupshup API, Can we send message on given whatsup group?

Referred link : https://www.gupshup.io/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like groups messaging is deprecated by Whatsapp

> We are announcing the deprecation of Groups through the WhatsApp Business API. Starting July 8, 2020, only API phone numbers in a group created prior to July 8th can continue to use/manage Groups through the WhatsApp Business API. All other API phone numbers won’t be able to create/manage Groups through the Whatsapp Business API. On October 8, 2020, we will deprecate this feature for all API phone numbers (i.e., API phone numbers will be removed from their groups and no longer be able to send messages to their group).
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/group

And how you going to onboard all group members to you org? Message sending allowed only for opted in numbers.